# Spring EmbeddedKafka producer not waiting for consumer acknowledgement

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, embedded-kafka

I want the producer in my test to wait until the consumer in the class-under-test has acknowledged by calling `Acknowledgement.acknowledge()`. My consumer is initialized with the following properties:

```
spring:
  kafka:
    consumer:
      group-id: test-group
      bootstrap-servers: ${spring.embedded.kafka.brokers}
      enable-auto-commit: false
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
      max-poll-records: 1
```

My `kafkaListenerContainerFactory` is initialized as follows:

```
@Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, MessageType> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
            ConsumerFactory<String, MessageType> consumerFactory)
    {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, MessageType> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
        factory.setErrorHandler(new LoggingErrorHandler());
        factory.setConcurrency(numListeners);
        return factory;
    }
```

I have also set `acks` in my producer config to `all`. The producer doesn't seem to block though even though I'm waiting on the future returned.

```
producer.send(new ProducerRecord<Integer, String>(TOPIC, key, value)).get();
```

How can I get the producer in my test to block until the consumer acknowledges without adding some sort of `sleep`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot; producers and consumers are independent; `acks` are simply to acknowledge that the broker has received and secured the record; it has nothing to do with the consumer side.

You need your own logic for the consumer to tell the producer it has received the record.